# How to call a JS function after AJAX call to database is completely done

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I'm having trouble with an AJAX call.

```
var updateData = function(param, value)
{
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ajax_router,
    data: 'param='+param+'&value='+value,
    success: reloadList()
    });
}
```

Unfortunately the reloadList() function is called too soon. The page doesn't reload with the new data. When I hit F5 the new data is here so the database update works, it's just a matter of calling the reloadList() function at the right time.

I also tried with complete: reloadList() but it didn't work either.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the brackets from `reloadList()`.

You're calling the function immediately, instead of passing the function itself in the `success:` handler.

Comment: (There is no "reference"; only a function-object value .. essay for another day.)

Comment: @pst ok, slightly loose terminology, but it's the easiest term to understand.  FWIW, ES5 uses "Function object" (note case) rather than "function-objects".